# Determine the properties of the solution of a second order linear ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to a 2nd order linear ODE. $$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$$ where $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are both continuous.

Prove that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ have maxima or minima at the same point in $I$, then they cannot be
a fundamental set of solutions on that interval.

What i tried

A fundamental set of solutions means that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent.

Hence we need to prove

$ y_1$ and $y_2$  have maxima and minima $\Rightarrow$ $ y_1$ and $y_2$ cannot be linearly independent

By the method of contrapositive, this is equivalent to proving

$ y_1$ and $y_2$ is linearly independent $\Rightarrow$  $ y_1$ and $y_2$  does have maxima and minima

The workskain of $ y_1$ and $y_2$ must not equals to $0$ for  $y_1$ and $y_2$ to be linearly independent.

Hence
     $$w(y_1,y_2)(t)=det  \left( \begin{smallmatrix} y_{1} & y_{2}\\ y'_{1} & y'_{2} \\\end{smallmatrix} \right)\neq0$$ which then gives $$y_1y'_2-y'_1y_2\neq0$$ by the chain rule, this becomes $$(y_1y_2)'\neq0$$ and we can see that since the derivative of $y_1y_2\neq0$, hence $y_1y_2$ cannot have a maxima or minima and this thus implies that $y_1y_2$ also cannot have a maxima or minima, hence proving the above theorem. Is my prove correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Wronskian, not "workscain"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have stopped at $y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2 \ne 0$.  If $y_1$ and $y_2$ had a minima or maxima at the same point, $y_1'$ and $y_2'$ would be $0$ there, and then $y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2$ would be $0$.  This is **not** the same as  $(y_1 y_2)' \ne 0$: $(y_1 y_2)' = y_1 y_2' + y_1' y_2$.

Answer (score 0):

suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ have a mxima/minima at the same point $x = a.$ that means $y_1(a) = y_2(a) = 0.$ then by uniqueness $y(x) = y_2(a)y_1(a) - y_1(a)y_2(x)$ is identically zero. therefore $y_1, y_2$ are linearly independent.